# Wildfly, WAR and virtual hosts

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, war, virtualhost

currently I have a problem with the following situation:

1. In Wildfly, virtual hosts are defined in the `standalone.xml` file.
2. To bind a deployed `.war`-Artifact to a virtual host, the virtual host is placed in the `jboss-web.xml` of the `.war`-Artifact.

which leads to the fact that the `.war`-Artifacts depend on the current (Wildfly) environment to work and are therefore not exchangeable, e.g. to store in a artifact store like Artifactory.

Is there a way to overcome the problem or are even the assumptions 1 and/or 2 wrong in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously and unbeknownst to me there is a way to use placeholders in certain deployment descriptors:

> jboss-descriptor-property-replacement is used to enable or disable property replacement in the following descriptors:

```
jboss-ejb3.xml
jboss-app.xml
jboss-web.xml
*-jms.xml
*-ds.xml
```

respectively

> spec-descriptor-property-replacement is used to enable or disable property replacement in the following descriptors:

```
ejb-jar.xml
persistence.xml
```

(https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.2/html/security_guide/enablingdisabling_descriptor_based_property_replacement1)